# Compare string with two cell in SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql

How to compare input from text box @Name with Name and Surname from my table, I want to compare string with Name + ' ' + Surname. I try this syntax but nothing happen.

```
command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, Surname, DriverPID FROM Drivers WHERE (Name + ' ' + Surname) = @Name", connection);
```

Comment: I think **casing** might be an issue .. mind transforming them to upper and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is seemingly nothing wrong with your SQL syntax. Can you confirm you're passing the correct value in?

And confirm that data should be returned by running a standalone SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is working, my mistake. I was taking input for string from wrong textbox. That is really common source of errors.

Comment: It really isn't.  Please note you should make sure the strings are in the same case.  Bacause Dog Black and dog Black are not technically equal.

Comment: @Ramhound - That would depend on the database collation in SQL server and I believe the default is case insensitive SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS